# Is it possible to use trained patch classifier as image classifier?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, neural-network

Is it possible to use trained image patch classifier as image classifier?
For example, I trained CNN with image patches 28 x 28 grayscale image so the input will be `X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 28, 28, 1])`.

Can I use this trained model to classify one image as whole rather than as image patches? For example, the image size is 299 x 299 grayscale image.

Any suggestion will help. Thanks

Comment: I'm not clear how you want to apply the patch classifier to the image.  If you shrank the image through max pooling would that accomplish what you're looking for?

Comment: it's different, it's not that I want to use different image size during the training but when testing. if I use another layer e.g. maxpool then it has to be done in training phase.